# Calling an API multiple times from another API in flask

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and I want to call an API (say B) from another API (say A) multiple times. To explain more clearly, I get a list of items when A is called. There is a task (B) which needs to be done for each of those items. B has been written already so I thought, why not call B on each item in the list I get in A? That is when I came across `redirect`. But in all the examples I see, it is used in the final `return` statement making it effectively a 1 time redirection to another URL.

What I would like to do is:

```
# In API A
status = []
for item in items:
    status.append(<some_way_to_call_B>(item))    # status will contain the responses of every API call
return Jsonify(status)    # front-end shows which were successful and which weren't
```

Is it possible?

Comment: are both the APIs part of same app  ?

Comment: @FaizanNaseer Yes, they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use python `requests` to call the endpoint `A` inside endpoint `B`

eg:

```
@app.route("/A"):
def somefuncA():
    #some stuff to do
    return jsonify(result)

@app.route("/B"):
def somefuncB():

    #some stuff to do
    response = requests.get("<IP>/A")
    #use the result as desired

    return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: I totally missed it! :p